# Retrive receiver transaction details based on sender/receiver transaction id in paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I have a business paypal account. In many case, my customer just payment in my paypal account directly and give me his paypal transaction ID. I can search in my paypal account, from [transaction](https://www.paypal.com/activities) page. But it is time consuming because, I have to input the data  manualy and process the order accordingly. I know there is a way to implement that search feature in website using paypal API. But I am not sure which API should I use for this function.

Answer (score 0):

With the PayPal API, you can only search for transaction IDs that are your own PayPal account's transaction ID. You cannot search for the customer's PayPal transaction ID, which is different.

You can download PayPal reports that might contain their transaction ID, and you can search for that transaction ID in the PayPal web interface. No API.

Comment: nope there is a system. I do the same thing with my suppliers.

Comment: If you have their API credentials or permissions, yes. But not otherwise.

Comment: how to to that? Because I have API credentials